# How to use http to send json

Tags: json, http, post, apachebench, httpie

I am very new to http commands and apache bench, trying to do a simple benchmark. I had a question about how to send a json file usine httpie.

I saw an old example that used an older cli to do it like this:

```
http --verbose post example.org file.json --content-type="application/json"
```

However, I am unsure how to do this in httpie. I know that this part:

```
http --verbose post example.org
```

Would remain the same. But I don't know how I would do:

```
file.json --content-type="application/json
```

in httpie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest HTTPie command for sending a JSON file:

```
$ http example.org @file.json
```

https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#request-data-from-a-filename

Comment: Very concise and simple explanation. Thank you very much! The end result was: http --verbose post example.org @file.json